# Deliberation by or of

Tags: prepositions

What is error in the following sentence?

> The deliberations by the committee are completely confidential.

On googling I found **by** should be replaced with **of**.
But I think there is nothing wrong with **by**, because deliberation is a process and it can be done by a person.

Comment: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/15512169.2015.1016036.

Comment: ...........and with regard to "the deliberations of the committee", I would much prefer to see "the committee's deliberations".  It just sits better.